# Does calling .join() on a co-routine job wait for it's children to complete?

Tags: kotlin-coroutines

I am trying to understand parent/child relationship between jobs, so this main function

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) = runBlocking {
    val outer = launch {
        launch {
            repeat(1000) {
                print('.')
                delay(1)
            }
        }
    }
    outer.join()
    println("Finished")
}
```

according to the video I'm watching, says `Finished` should be printed and `main` should return before all `1000 dots` are printed.

Instead I'm seeing all the dots printed, and then `Finished` printed

> ........................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................Finished

Is the video wrong?

Answer (score 0):

So I shared the screenshot of the console in the vide, and someone pointed out that the API looks really old LOL. Also the video is retired, and there is a new one.

[image]

[image]

And according to here: https://kt.academy/article/cc-job

> a parent suspends until all the children are finished;